# How To correctly set Parameters for Function with LinQ and List<T>?

Tags: c#, list, linq, types

I am struggling with the parameters for my `IEnumerable<ISeries>` function.

I created an `interface AllProperties`, which combines all the properties from different classes that I am going to need at some point.

This is my `IEnumerable<ISeries> GetDepartments` right now:

```
public IEnumerable<ISeries> GetDepartments()
        {
            IEnumerable<ISeries> series = Employees.GroupBy(x => x.Department).ToList().Select(x => new PieSeries<double>
            {
                Values = new List<double> { x.Count() },
                Name = x.Key,
            });

            return series;
        }
```

It works perfectly fine, but I'll have to copy/paste the code for each List and Property and I would like to avoid that.

The idea of the function I am trying to create is, that I reference a `List` and a given property and return an `IEnumerable<ISeries>`

This is what I got so far:

```
        public IEnumerable<ISeries> GetEnumerableGroupBy<T,TKey>(List<T> list, Func<AllProperties, TKey> myGroupingProperty) 
        {

            IEnumerable<ISeries> series = list.GroupBy(myGroupingProperty).ToList().Select(x => new PieSeries<double>
            {
                Values = new List<double> { x.Count() },
                Name = x.ToString(),
            });

            return series;
        }

//Calling the function like this
GetEnumerableGroupBy(Employees, x => x.Department);
```

now I am getting the error, that `List<T>` does not contain a definition for `GroupBy` and I don't know how to fix this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The concept of creating a `AllProperties` interface sounds like fixing it the wrong way. For me to little context to give a better solution.

Comment: Instead of `AllProperties`, your argument needs to be `Func<T, TKey> myGroupingProperty>`.

Comment: Also get rid of that `ToList()`, it doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: What is the purpose of setting `Values` to a list of one item?

Comment: @NetMage: Presumably this is setting up data for a pie chart that might support multiple series of data, but in this use case there's only one series they want to display?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close. You don't need the `AllProperties` interface at all. Instead, just make your function argument the generic `T` type.

```
public IEnumerable<ISeries> GetEnumerableGroupBy<T, TKey>(List<T> list, Func<T, TKey> myGroupingProperty)
{
   ...
}
```

The rest of your code should work just fine.

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked like a charm!
Creating the interface felt really wrong, so I'm glad I dont have to use that anymore.